# Dart, float for loop will cause strange result

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    priceValue.add(54.99 + i*5);
    print(54.99 + i*5);
}
```

Result:

```
js_primitives.dart:30 54.99
js_primitives.dart:30 59.99
js_primitives.dart:30 64.99000000000001
js_primitives.dart:30 69.99000000000001
js_primitives.dart:30 74.99000000000001
js_primitives.dart:30 79.99000000000001
js_primitives.dart:30 84.99000000000001
js_primitives.dart:30 89.99000000000001
js_primitives.dart:30 94.99000000000001
js_primitives.dart:30 99.99000000000001
```

What causes the `00000000001` to appear?

Comment: Floating point numbers finite precision?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just how double numbers work. You would get the same result in other languages that use the same doubles as Dart (they are standardized as [IEEE-754 64-bit floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)).

The crux is that, e.g., 89.99 cannot be represented exactly by the precision of doubles. Doubles are *binary* numbers with at most 53 significant bits.
In binary, 89.99 doesn't have a finite representation, just like 1/3 cannot be written finitely as a decimal number (0.3333333.... it's never enough for the precise value).

There are only a finite number of double values, spread throughout the range that doubles cover. So, when you try to convert a "real" number to a double, the computer rounds to the *closest* double value to the original number.

Even 54.99 isn't precise. The actual double value of `54.99` is the *double* closest to the mathematical number 54.99 (aka 5499/100):

> 54.99000000000000198951966012828052043914794921875

Then you add 35 to that, which again isn't representable as a double, and the double hardware picks the closest double to that value:

> 89.990000000000009094947017729282379150390625

Due to the imprecission on the original 54.99, that is actually a different double than the one that would be picked for just writing `89.99`, which is:

> 89.9899999999999948840923025272786617279052734375

When you convert a double to a string, the algorithm for picking a representation is actually clever. It picks the *shortest* decimal representation where the numerical value will be rounded to the original double value.

So, since `54.99 + 35` is not the same double as `89.99`, they need to have different string representations. The string `89.99` is obviously taken for the latter, so `54.99 + 35` needs more digits to distinguish itself. That's where the trailing `00000000000001` comes from.

So, in short, it's just what doubles do. The same computation will give the same result in most other languages that use the same double type.