# For loop increment double precisely

Tags: dart

I want to create a For-loop that add values to a list from 0.1 to 0.9. I did the following:

```
final List<double> speechRateValues = [];

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      double value = 0.1 * j;
      speechRateValues.add(value);
    }
```

The problem is that my list is:

[image: List]

Is it possible to the 0.3000000... be just 0.3, and so on? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I read on another post a comment saying: "To prevent being bitten by artifacts of floating point arithmetic, you might want to use an integer loop variable and derive the floating point value you need inside your loop" so I did this way, but this still get "wrong" values

Comment: If you are asking about this other way you did it, *show* what it is.

Comment: Sorry, the post already shows "the other way".

Comment: This is the nature of floating point numbers – they're an approximation. The error in this case is less than one part in a million billion, which is extraordinarily close to zero, and for speech rates surely irrelevant. When you output the values you can use `toStringAsFixed` to format it in a way that disguises the very slight approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking that this variation could cause trouble. But, as shown in this post: [Dart, float for loop will cause strange result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44557990/dart-float-for-loop-will-cause-strange-result) (thanks, [Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter)), this is how double number works, and in this case, this variation is irrelevant.

PS. To output the value, I can just use `toStringAsFixed` (to show 0.3, for example, properly) like [motto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21146235/motto) said.